# Htaccess ignore certain subdomains for a redirect not working as expected

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

First of all, what is the different between these 2 methods, and which method is better?

```
#method 1
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|catalog|demo|dev|whatever)\.example\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/index/parser.php?%2&domain_name=example.com [QSA,L]

#method 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^catalog\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^demo\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^whatever\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/index/parser.php?%1&domain_name=example.com [L,R]
```

Both methods seem to work the same, but both methods also make it so one of the subdomains are not ignored. All are ignored except for demo. This is what I am trying to figure out.

In whm, cpanel, enom, and everywhere is the same for all the subdomains, so what is different about the one subdomain? In each subdirectory for whatever app is in there is different, but nothing looks suspicious as to why it wouldn't work for a particular subdomain. I don't even think it's getting that far to reach and read the subdirectory. The htaccess rule is redirecting to the parser instead of ignoring the subdomain so it goes to subdirectory instead for the demo subdomain. What do i need to look at and where? What in htaccess? What in whm? What in cpanel? What somewhere else? What could be causing this?

Comment: Is there another .htaccess inside site root of `demo` subdomain?

Comment: no htaccess in demo folder